# How do I connect to a Zebra printer over RS232?

Tags: c++, printing, serial-port

I purchased a Zebra LP 2844 label printer and would like to send ZPLII print jobs to it from a C++ program. I am able to connect to the printer and print test labels using the Zebra Setup Utilities software, but am unable to connect to it using a serial monitor. I tried using different serial monitors but all of them gave some sort of COM port error when I tried to connect.

Am I wrong in thinking that I can simply connect to the printer over the COM port and send the ASCII data to it?

Comment: Are you getting your error when you are opening the port or when you are trying to send data?

Comment: @MarkHall - I'm getting an error when trying to open the port. I've tried doing it with C++ code that I know works, and I've also tried with a number of serial port monitors. For example, here are two errors I got when attempting to open the serial port:  
SuperMon: "Comm Port Error", 
RealTerm: "Apro exception." However, when I open up the Zebra Setup Utilities program it has no trouble communicating with the printer. This really perplexes me.

Comment: How about adding your port opening code to your question, it would probably help to see it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I figured out the problem, though! I'll post the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, because the printer was installed as, well, a printer (lol), Windows wouldn't let me open the COM port. After disassociating the printer in control panel from the COM port, I was able to open it!

Comment: How did you disassociated it?

Comment: @SterlingDiaz Go to devices and printers, right click on the printer, select printer properties, click on the ports tab, and uncheck the com port (I *think* that's how I did it, but it's been a while..).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know how already, you'll need to learn how to use Serial/Comm communication in C++ on Windows, or whatever platform you're planning on using. As far as printing ASCII data to it, most barcode printers use some sort of protocol over serial that defines how the label is formatted. I don't know enough Zebra barcode printers to tell you what that protocol is. Many of them even support multiple protocol types.

If you can tell me what the model number of the printer you're working with is, I'll see if I can find any information on the protocol it uses/supports.

Comment: Hey @druciferre, thanks for your reply. I've figured out how to communicate over a COM port with a microcontroller using C++, so I'm assuming it'll be the same with this.  
  
The printer model is Zebra LP 2844, and I'm pretty sure the format it receives data in (for printing) is the EPL language. There's a lot of documentation online for EPL, so that shouldn't be a problem, the problem is I can't seem to connect to the printer.